# How to access control of a nested formGroup which is in same template

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

**Required Field**
      
      
      Submit

```
<button (click)="setPreset()">Set preset</button>
```

Here I'm getting an error saying 'controls of undefined'. This is because name: FormGroup is not defined.
It could be accessible if I replace the line with 
Required Field

This looks like accessing a deep nested property. Is there a way I could access it through the group name directly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post code for your formgroup and the HTML, very difficult to guess from this line

Comment: Sorry, Code was missed out. I have posted the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301649/how-to-access-the-control-directly-by-its-formgroupname