# How to access the control directly by its formGroupName

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

In This form I have to access the control of formControlName="last" to show errors of it.

`<div [formGroup]="form">`
    `<div formGroupName="name">`
        `<input formControlName="first" placeholder="First name">`
        `<input formControlName="last" placeholder="Last name">`
        **`<span *ngIf="name['controls'].last.invalid">invalid</span>`**
    `</div>`
    `<input formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">`
    `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`
`</div>`

This code has thrown an error 'controls' of undefined(**Bold Formatted line**).
control could be accessible by form['controls'].name['controls'].last.invalid , but is there any way I could access the control directly by its formGroupName ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div *ngIf="!form.controls.name.controls.last.valid">
       Invalid last name !!
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Veena,
form.controls.name.controls.last.valid works(mentioned in question also).
But I wanted to access the control through it formGroupName.

Comment: If there are many deep nested FormGroups formed with formGroupNames, then it becomes difficult to access it. We would need to access it though "form.controls.group1.controls.group2.controls.group3.controls.controlName", which is very lengthy. That's the reason I wanted to access it through its group name itself.

@Veena Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

Could you try below snippet

`<span *ngIf="form.get('last').invalid">invalid</span>`

Answer (score 0):

@sravanponugoti: we cannot use [formGroup] with  in angular. 
Try this code

```
<form [formGroup]="form"> 
<div formGroupName="name"> 
<input formControlName="first" placeholder="First">
<input formControlName="last" placeholder="Last"> 
<span *ngIf="form.controls['name'].controls.last.valid">invalid</s‌​pan> 
</div> 
<input formControlName="email" placeholder="Email"> 
<button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```